# Export data to excel(.XLSX format), structure in side the XL sheet is custom

Tags: javascript, sapui5

How do I export data to excel(xlsx format) in UI5, structure in side the XL sheet is custom it is not like exporting entire table into XL. Data is coming from oData service, Please see the attachment for the format of the data inside the XL.

[xl data format screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szhWJ.png)

in the XL we see on document and two lines, there can be more than one documents in that case we should see each document and followed by its line items.

I should be able to give file name and the sheet name inside the file
XL should have a header
it should be in .xlsx format

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: UI5's job is not creating excel files so your question should not be related with UI5.

If you want to create the excel file in the backend and your backend is a SAP NetWeaver system, use [abap2xlsx](https://github.com/ivanfemia/abap2xlsx).

If you want to create the excel file in the frontend, I recommend using [SheetJS](https://sheetjs.com). There are many examples on their website and GitHub repository, apart from many questions here at SO on this topic.

As you need freedom to create the file with a specific content, formatting and file name, making a call to an oData Service (assuming you have one) using ?$format=xlsx is not an option for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I want to create the excel in the frontend.

Comment: I need help with how to export data to XL  in UI5 using SheetJS

Comment: This is another question that in order to help you, you must provide what have you tried in this different question.